# Analogous filter to Kalman filter that maximized mode instead (as opposed to minimizing variance)

Tags: signal-analysis, filters

I may have a potential application where maximizing the mode (as opposed to typically minimizing the variance) would be useful for state estimates. The situation may arise from skewed distributions where the mode is of more interest than the mean. I was wondering if anyone has seen a filter like this before? Thank you.

Josh

Comment: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/